# ORA-06502: character string buffer too small. Even though the string size is under declared size limit

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
 FOR this_loop
     IN (SELECT field_A, field_B
           FROM TABLE_NAME
          WHERE    num = i_num)
  LOOP
     IF this_loop.field_B BETWEEN 1 AND 3
     THEN
        v_A :=  v_A || ' ' || this_loop.field_A;
     ELSIF this_loop.field_B BETWEEN 4 AND 8
     THEN
        v_field_A := v_field_A || ' ' || this_loop.field_A;  -- Error is at this line
     ELSIF this_loop.field_B BETWEEN 9 AND 15
     THEN
        v_B :=  v_B || ' ' || this_loop.field_A;
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
```

Variable decalared as

```
v_field_A            VARCHAR2 (100);
```

What I know -

1. Variable v_field_A cannot hold value more than 100 characters
2. The output I get from the `SELECT` Query doesn't have more than 10 characters.

My question - How is even possible to face this issue of space buffer when the characters are whitin the limit of varchar2 ?
I have faced this issue few years back but last time the cause was output of `select` query. It had more than 100 characters and hence the size issue but this time it is not more than 10 characters. I'm confused. Any help is appreciated

Comment: how many rows do you have in your table?

Comment: There are over million rows but this happens only with few rows.

Comment: to be more specific, how many rows does the loop fetch? 10 char * 11 loop iterations == you'll run into the error since you keep concatenating value to the variable on every iteration

Comment: why cant you increase the size of  v_field_A   ? this will resolve the issue

Comment: @Sathya It depends. Usually it's not more than 3-4 rows.

Comment: @Dawn I don't have the privileges to edit. Apart from that, even if I could edit, i would need to know why is this happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Variable v_field_A cannot hold value more than 100 characters

Why not? It is very much possible since you are **concatenating** the variable for each row in the **CURSOR FOR LOOP**.

For example,

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_name VARCHAR2(50);
  3  BEGIN
  4    FOR i IN
  5    (SELECT ename FROM emp
  6    )
  7    LOOP
  8      v_name := v_name || i.ename;
  9    END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Use **DBMS_OUTPUT** to see the current size of the variable and the new value being appended.

**Let's debug**

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_name VARCHAR2(50);
  3  BEGIN
  4    FOR i IN
  5    (SELECT ename FROM emp
  6    )
  7    LOOP
  8      dbms_output.put_line('Length of new value = '||LENGTH(i.ename));
  9      v_name := v_name || i.ename;
 10      dbms_output.put_line('Length of variable = '||LENGTH(v_name));
 11    END LOOP;
 12  END;
 13  /
Length of new value = 5
Length of variable = 5
Length of new value = 5
Length of variable = 10
Length of new value = 4
Length of variable = 14
Length of new value = 5
Length of variable = 19
Length of new value = 6
Length of variable = 25
Length of new value = 5
Length of variable = 30
Length of new value = 5
Length of variable = 35
Length of new value = 5
Length of variable = 40
Length of new value = 4
Length of variable = 44
Length of new value = 6
Length of variable = 50
Length of new value = 5
```

**Error**

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 9
```

It is pretty clear, we wanted to concatenate a string with length `5` to the variable declared as max size `50`, currently holding a value of size `50`. hence, it throws the error `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. if the variable can hold more than 50 or 100 characters. The problem of size shouldn't be there at all, right ?

Comment: @PirateX You are forgetting the fact that you are concatenating the values to the variable in the loop, therefore, at some point, while iterating through the roes, it exceeds the declared size. I have added an example in my answer.

Comment: Ok I think i got the idea. It's concatenation, which at some point exceeds the limit of 100 thereby throwing an error. Right ?

Comment: @PirateX Exactly. That is what you see in the DBMS_OUTPUT in the example I have shown you.

Comment: @PirateX Please mark it as answered, would help others too! I see none of your questions have ever been marked as answered. It is a good gesture and suggested by the community to accept the answer which resolves your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

11 rows * 10 character > 100 characters => error - your concatenating many rows of 10 characters together into a one of three variables.  One of them will be growing each time through the loop.

What am I missing?

Also beware of characters versus bytes.  In a varchar2, each CHARACTER will likely take 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the string concatenation in a SQL query:

```
SELECT field_A,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN field_B BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN field_A END, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY field_A) as val1,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN field_B BETWEEN 4 AND 8 THEN field_A END, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY field_A) as val2,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN field_B BETWEEN 9 AND 15 THEN field_A END, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY field_A) as val3
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE num = i_num;
```

This is intended to simplify your code.  You are still limited by Oracle string lengths.  You can get around the Oracle limit in PL/SQL using a CLOB, but that is unnecessary when the final string is only a few hundred characters.

Comment: Even `LISTAGG` has a **SQL limit** of `4000`.

Answer (score 0):

Check how many times this condition is being executed and what values are being concatenated. Since this being concatenated multiple number of times  there is a possibility that  size of v_field_A is going beyond 50 characters

```
ELSIF this_loop.field_B BETWEEN 4 AND 8
 THEN
    v_field_A := v_field_A || ' ' || this_loop.field_A;
```

To resolve this you can increase the size of this variable. You can declare a varchar upto 32,767 bytes

Answer (score 0):

> The answer to your question lies in how many times the loop
>   executes and how many times it goes inside IF condition.

***EXAMPLE :***

**Condition** : BETWEEN **4** AND **8**

this_loop.field_A:= 'test';

**Number of times loop executes** = 100

Due to **CONCATINATION** the size will definitely shoot up more than 100 CHAR.

Similar will the case with other LOOP conditions.

**Solution** : Try using **CLOB** instead of **VARCHAR** to eliminate this issue.

Oracle error are very descriptive. If it throws some error it pretty much explains the scenario :P.